# Using regsvr32, do you need to unregister a dll or ocx before registering it again?

Tags: dll, regsvr32

Using regsvr32, do you need to unregister a dll or ocx before registering it again?

Or will registering it do that anyway?

Comment: Have you actually tried it. IIRC, if you try to register it without unregistering it first, you will get a message complaining as such.

Comment: You don't get a message.

Answer (score 3):

You need to unregister before re-registering. It's not automatic.

Comment: I'm still puzzling over this one.  If it is being registered again, then why is it necessary to unregister it first?

Comment: Because otherwise it is possible to mess up the registry with multiple versions. In some cases re-registering an older version may cause a dependancy conflict with inter-dependant applications.

Answer (score 2):

`regsvr32` calls an entrypoint (DllRegisterServer) in the DLL to do the registration, so I suppose it could possibly be DLL-dependent.  But in general, the registration entrypoint simply updates the information in the registry.  So there would be no need to unregister it first.  For example, an OLE DB provider I helped write updates the GUID information and path to the DLL during the registration.  There is no reason to unregister it in that case.

Answer (score 2):

You don't *have* to but it might mess you up if you don't...